# Valid domain model while using Automapper

Tags: domain-driven-design, automapper, domain-model

I am using Jimmy Bogard's lovely Automapper to map my API model to the POCO classes (domain model).
The API model does not contain certain attributes of the domain model which are necessary for the domain model to be in valid state. In this scenario, when Automapper finishes its job, I have a fully constructed domain model in an invalid state.
Not using Automapper is not an option because there are too many attributes to hand code.

So, here is my question:

How do I use automapper to create the object in this manner while leaving the domain model in a valid state.

Thanks

Comment: You don't. Automapper is not meant for that kind of usage

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too long for a comment:

Although Jimmy's answer is correct it *may* imply that your design may not be as encapsulated as it could be since you are going to have to expose a lot of state.  This may be why there are comments around "anemic" models and "not fit for purpose".

If you are focused on behaviour then you may have something, totally hypothetical, as follows to make your customer a *Gold* customer:

```
customer.MakeGold();
```

However, using state you would now have to expose attributes that allow you to map to a *Gold* status.  Internally your customer may have checked certain other state to determine the validity of the *Gold* status whereas that *validity* check has now moved out of the domain in the way Jimmy says he makes sure that the state is correct before passing it to the domain.

This is not so much an auto-mapper issue as it is a design issue.  It also seems to indicate that your API/Integration model may be more data-centric.

On the other hand, if you are mapping to, say, command-style value objects that are handed to the domain it may not be as bad as that :)

```
// map my APIActivationDetails to Activate --- however automapper does this :)

var activate = AutoMapper.Map<Activate>().From(apiActivationDetails);

customer.Activate(activate);
```

Come to think of it... this seems to be what Jimmy is saying :P

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm saying. But the command is validated at the application boundary, which can also look across entities/aggregates as needed.

Answer (score 1):

> "to map my API model to the POCO classes (domain model)"

Why would you ever want to map command object (your API model) attributes to domain objects? If that's what you are aiming for you will mostly end up with over-engineered CRUD, but certainly not a DDD solution.

Behaviors should be explicitly declared on aggregates and aggregates are responsible for mutating their own internal state according to the business invariants they protect.

That way, domain model clients can clearly state their intention and this intention isin't lost through the business process.

You shouldn't try to shove data into aggregates, instead you should ask them to perform a task.

Comment: Inside your domain, you could certainly use AutoMapper, though, when it makes sense. I usually don't.

Comment: Do you have an example where it would make sense?

Comment: If I am just editing data and not doing something terribly behavioral. Editing an invoice vs. approving an invoice.

Comment: @JimmyBogard Well, editing an invoice may just as well be a sequence of behavioral operations: LineItemQuantityAdjusted, LineItemRemoved...etc. If you do not capture the intention then you are just doing CRUD. CRUD may be fine though, but then it doesn't require a domain model at all.

Answer (score 0):

I validate the API model *before* it gets mapped into my domain model, whether I'm using AutoMapper or not. The API model represents a command or action, so I'm validating the command before I apply it to my entity, not mutate my entity and then try to validate it afterwards. This also means all my validation attributes are on my API model.

Comment: So you prefer not always-valid anemic domain models?

Comment: No, I validate commands before they ever hit my domain model, so my domain model is always valid.

Comment: I agree that there is some trivial validations that can be performed in commands, but it's the aggregates role to protect invariants.

Comment: OK so you can make your aggregates "do validation" - but I warn you, validation frameworks do validation very well, hand-rolled objects do not, and surfacing validation errors from inside entities/aggregates is awwwwwful. Satisfying invariants isn't about performing validation necessarily - it's about correct state.

Comment: The domain model is meant to effectively express business logic and protect invariants. Invariants that depends on the state of the business belongs inside aggregates. I'd even go further and say that most validation rules belong to the domain (e.g. having a Username value object to enforce username formats). However, while these modeling techiques are very efficient at enforcing policies, they aren't for error reporting. For that reason, validation frameworks can be used either in the UI or the application layer to perform validations that mostly aren't dependent on the business state.

Comment: This approach leads to some degree of duplication for trivial rules, but I don't see it as duplication because the goal is quite different. The domain model protects the state of the business while UI & application layer validations helps the user in the accomplishment of their tasks.

Comment: My validation rules are in my domain. My domain consists of validators, handlers, and entities. I just don't put my validation inside my entities, that gets yucky. And I don't duplicate these rules, everything in my system flows through commands and queries, but rules MUST be associated with commands.

Comment: That's one way of viewing it, but then that's not what the always-valid paradigm is. http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/05/22/always-valid/

Comment: Well, good luck! We kinda opted for what's easy/possible in C#/.NET, and what we could effectively prevent with pull request code reviews.

Comment: So I'm wondering if this is really about applying an incoming request to a domain model or restoring a domain model's state? If I protect my domain model the way plalx describes (which I prefer), i'm still faced with the challenge of restoring state to the object (e.g. from a database). The model has private setters so I can't really deserialize, so I'm left with doing sort of a `.LoadFromState` method with a `.GetState` method I'm actually trying to figure out if I can at least use AutoMapper in there somehow